# How to round all the numbers in a string with Reg Exp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on an SVG minifier. And I came to this needs. SVG contains a lot of numbers in it as strings, for instance:

```
123.66 12.50 162.9873 23.67
```

I would like to change them to:

```
124 13 163 24
```

What I have tried is first to remove the long digits:

```
// reduce the decimal to only 1 digit
source=source.replace(/(\d\.\d)\d+/g ,'$1');
```

And then, I tried

```
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.1/g,'$1');
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.2/g,'$1');
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.3/g,'$1');
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.4/g,'$1');
```

to replace `6.1` or `7.2` with `6` or `7` is very simple as showed above. But how could I turn `6.8` into `7` or `9.9` into `10`?

I have tried this, but not working:

```
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.6/g,Number('$1')+1);
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.7/g,Number('$1')+1);
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.8/g,Number('$1')+1);
source=source.replace(/(\d)\.9/g,Number('$1')+1);
```

Any tips on that?

Comment: Use a [function as the second argument for `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). Then use `round`.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to select the decimals as well (when they exist), then pass a function as the replacer which `round`s them:

```js
const str = '123.66 12.50 162.9873 23.67 23.22';
console.log(
  str.replace(/\d+\.\d+/g, Math.round)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Math.round($i)`, no need to deal with the data as strings. Integers are more suitable for your use case.